# includepdf doesn't work with PDF with multiple pages

Tags: pdfpages

I have a problem with the `includepdf` command. I have tried to include my pdf file in a .tex file. I compile my .tex file with `XeLaTeX`. XeLaTeX only shows the first page of the .pdf file. However, when I change XeLaTeX to pdflatex it works normally, but my language doesn't work with pdflatex. It works only with XeLaTeX. Therefore, I have only one choice, to use XeLaTeX to compile my .tex file.

This is my sample code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}

    \includepdf[scale=0.75,pages=-]{"Heliyon.pdf"}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should probably also note what language you're using as there are no language settings in this example. I have no issues with the example no matter what I use. So please make sure to provide code that actually fails for your with `xelatex` otherwise we cannot test.

Comment: @PisitNakjai You can probably use LuaLaTeX. It should support all languages supported by XeLaTeX and uses the same PDF inclusion infrastructure as pdfLaTeX.

Comment: remove the quotes around the file name.

Comment: oops, my bad, I also have only one page on that example using xelatex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not add unnessary quotes around the file name. A current latex does the quoting internally and the additional quotes can confuse the engines. So for me with xelatex this loads only one page:

```
\includepdf[scale=0.75,pages=-]{"example-image-a4-numbered.pdf"}
```

But this works perfectly and loads all 12 pages:

```
\includepdf[scale=0.75,pages=-]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}
```